# What is the usage of AccessibleRole property in a user control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, accessibility

there are two properties with these names in user control :

1- AccessibleName
2- AccessibleRole

What are these properties and what's their usages in an win form application?
I have already take a look at MSDN but unfortunately I couldn't understand their descriptions?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 22):

Those are special attributes that can be used by screen readers or text-to-speech programs to make your program accessible to people with disabilities or who use assistive technology.

`AccessibleName` can be used to tell the user the element the cursor is sitting in. E.g. the assistive technology program can't determin which label around the text box belongs to it, but it's able to read that attribute (i.e. "what's the meaning of this box?"). A more detailed description can be added to `AccessibleDescription`.

In a similar way `AccessibleRole` describes the user (or tells the tool) what kind of control this is. This isn't as important for the standard controls, but imagine some custom button or hyperlink control: With this attribute it's able to tell "Hey, I'm clickable and I'm a button/link!".

Comment: When does the screen reader reads the information present in AccessibleDescription field? I'm normally observing that screen reader reads the information present in AccessibleName field only. Will it make any difference to the screen reader if I change the AccessibleRole of a listView control to table? Actually a tabular structure is possible in listView control with the help of its columns property but screen readers don't read it in that fashion. It simply reads the text of first column. I want screen reader to read all the column value one by one whenever user selects a row of list item.

Comment: @RBT never used one, but this sounds like an excellent standalone question

Comment: @Mario atleast I was able to figure out the table stuff related to list view thing. I was using JAWS as my screen reading tool. The default setting of JAWS is to read all the values in all the columns of a row without reading the header text. You can configure JAWS to read column header text as well. If you want to explicitly read the column header text at any given point of time when focus is on your list view then just press Insert + Ctrl + <Column Index Number> and JAWS will read out loud the value of column header and column value. Here column Index Number is 1-based unlike arrays.